# Why can I not sort a contourArea with openCV4

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to follow [this](https://pysource.com/2019/01/04/eye-motion-tracking-opencv-with-python/?unapproved=739&moderation-hash=3f2830de42eefbc43bd4ab873d9ebf61#comment-739) tutorial.
I use openCV4 (openCV3 is used in the tutorial). I can't fix an error about sorted the contours that's why i need your help.

I have looked for similar error on topics, I've tried [this](https://answers.opencv.org/question/102465/error-calling-contourarea/) but doesn't work. I get this error: IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True: #Infinite loop to work on all the pictures
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret is False:
        break

    roi = frame
    rows, cols, _ = roi.shape
    gray_roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #converts color
    gray_roi = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_roi, (7, 7), 0) #Apply a gaussien filter

    _ , threshold, = cv2.threshold(gray_roi, 3, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) 
    _ , cnts = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    if cnts is None:
        print('No eyes found!')
    else:
        cnts = sorted(cnts, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)
        for cnt in cnts:
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

            cv2.rectangle(roi, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            cv2.line(roi, (x + int(w/2), 0), (x + int(w/2), rows), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.line(roi, (0, y + int(h/2)), (cols, y + int(h/2)), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            break

        #cv2.imshow("Threshold", threshold)
        #cv2.imshow("gray roi", gray_roi)
        #cv2.imshow("Roi", roi)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The output shows directly the error and don't even print 'No eyes found' (compared to when i get the index error)
Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eye_motion_tracking.py", line 22, in <module>
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)
  File "eye_motion_tracking.py", line 22, in <lambda>
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key=lambda x: cv2.contourArea(x), reverse=True)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) /home/rshah/opencv/opencv-4.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp:274: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'contourArea'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that OpenCV 4 changed the output parameters of `findContours`:

[OpenCV 3.4.6 `findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.6/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a):

```
image, contours, hierarchy  =   cv.findContours(    image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]  )
```

[OpenCV 4.0.0 `findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0)

```
contours, hierarchy =   cv.findContours(    image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]]  )
```

This means that your code is actually receiving the `hierarchy` instead of `contours`. Just change

```
    _ , cnts = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

to

```
    cnts = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```